# apexcharts Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am using vue-apexcharts, type bar to display data as x, y values.

```
data: [{"x":"Apr","y":1},{"x":"May","y":2}]
```

it works..

but when adding another entry that contains the y = 0

```
data: [{"x":"Apr","y":1},{"x":"May","y":2},{"x":"Jun","y":0}]
```

it display but in console I get a lot of errors like this:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN NaNCNaN NaN ..."
```

Is this a bug ? This issue is only when the Y value is 0, if there is a number greater then 0 there are no errors...

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

Downgrading from apexcharts 3.37.1 => 3.35.3 there are no errors ... so certainly is a bug in the latest version...

**UPDATE 2**

it seems the problem is fixed in 3.37.2 :)